# Where does Thymeleaf places the CSRF token by default?

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

Currently, Thymeleaf places the `CSRF` token as the first child of the `form`. Is this behavior mentioned anywhere and can we rely, that Thymeleaf will inject this field always as the first child of the related form?

My question concerns dealing with CSS `:first-child` `:last-child` selectors which won't work if the CSRF input field is placed wrong. `first-of-type` as a band aid is no solution.

Can anybody answer this question?